# for-in loop swift 4 two variables and increments

Tags: swift, for-loop, swift4, for-in-loop

I want to ask a question regarding for-in loops in swift 4. I want to set two variables and their increments:

j = 1, f = 87.5; j < numberOfGrids && f > (-90) ;  j++, f -= 2.5  { }

How can you convert this to Swift 4? I hope to hear back from you folks soon!

Comment: Unrelated, but did you really mean to start `j` at 1 and stop at `numberOfGrids - 1`? We often start w `0`...

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to iterate over two sequences, stopping when the shortest is exhausted. The first sequence is `1..<numberOfGrids`. The second is "values from 87.5 to -90 by -2.5" which is `stride(from: 87.5, to: -90, by: -2.5)`.

To iterate over two sequences, stopping when the shortest is exhausted, you use zip:

```
let grids = 1..<numberOfGrids
let fs = stride(from: 87.5, to: -90, by: -2.5) // not sure what "f" represents
for (j, f) in zip(grids, fs) {
    print(j, f)
}
```

Comment: Rob `to: -87.5` maybe (and likewise in text)?

Comment: @CRD, I believe that would give different results than the original code. It wouldn't include -87.5 (which the original code does).  `stride(from:to:by:)` doesn't include its endpoint. Are you thinking of `through:`?

Comment: Rob, apologies my bad

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code:

```
let numberOfGrid = 100
var j = 1
var f = 87.5
repeat {
    // Do something here
    j += 1
    f -= 2.5
    // Do something here
} while j < numberOfGrid && f > -90
```

Comment: qtngo thanks! what about using the for-in instead of the while?

Comment: Thanks Rob. So where would I replace it? Where it says repeat or erase the repeat and keep the while at the end? I'm confused.

Comment: Instead of `repeat { ... } while j < numberOfGrids && f > -90`, it’s just `while j < numberOfGrids && f > -90 { ... }`. The `for` loops perform the test at the start of the loop, like `while` does, not at the end, like `repeat`-`while` does. As an aside, I think qtngo’s basic approach (with the caveat of replacing `repeat`-`while` with just `while`) is the best way to achieve what you want. Rob Napier provided a good (as always), literal answer to your question, but I think a simple `while` loop lends itself to more intuitive code in this particular case. It’s admittedly subjective.

Comment: Thanks a lot you guys! Much love!